# Eventbrite - Is there a Teaser Text / Short Description Field?

Tags: text, eventbrite, teaser

I'll be using the Eventbrite API to pull an event list to display on a web page. I understand that there is a Description field, but, we would also like to display teaser text about the event. Does this type of field exist for an Eventbrite Event?

I have referred to the Eventbrite Event object found at....

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_get/

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Great suggestion!

Currently, Eventbrite events lack an official event 'summary' content field.

As a short-term solution, I would recommend starting with the 'description' field, stripping out any HTML tags that you find, and then truncating the resulting string to your desired length.

This additional data transformation work could be added to your API client code (if you are using a code library to connect to the Eventbrite API).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had thought about attempting like you suggested for the teaser description. Perhaps even determine that a specific portion (i.e. - paragraph 2) would always serve as the teaser summary for the client.